# Checkboxfor not binding model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So I'm new to MVC and ASP.Net. I've been reading through the posts on here all afternoon and I just can't get this to work. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675037/mvc3-using-checkbox-with-a-complex-viewmodel), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781730/checkboxfor-not-binding-with-nested-objects), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557897/how-to-bind-checkboxfor) and I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Condition Class

```
public class conditions
{
    public string condName;
    public bool condValue;

    public conditions(string s)
    {
        condName = s;

    }
}
```

Risk History Class

```
public class riskHistory
{
    public List<conditions> results;
    public riskHistory()
    {
        results = new List<conditions>();
        results.Add(new conditions("History of Marfans Syndrome"));
        results.Add(new conditions("Family history of aortic disease"));
        results.Add(new conditions("Recent aortic manipulation"));
        results.Add(new conditions("Known thorasic aorta aneurysm"));

    }
}
```

Now there is a riskPain and riskFeatures class defined the same way. I needed to split this into 3 because each has to be handled differently. What I display over each class unique in the view.

View Model defined as

```
public class adViewModel
    {
        public riskFeatures rF;


 public riskPain rP;
    public riskHistory rH;

    public adViewModel()
    {
        rF = new riskFeatures();
        rH = new riskHistory();
        rP = new riskPain();
    }
}
```

And then I have this code in the view. It's strongly typed to adViewModel.

```
Does the patient have any of the following history?
@for (int x =0; x<Model.rH.results.Count; x++)
{
    string n = Model.rH.results[x].condName.ToString();

    <b>@Html.Label(n)</b> @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.rH.results[x].condValue)
}



Does the patient have any of the following features to their pain?
```

// continue on to the other classes

The view displays correctly but when I submit the form it doesn't bind (all condvalue's are false). If you are going to suggest an editor template then I have a second question. The question in the view code above the for loop "Does the patient have the following history?" that question has to be different for each set of checkboxes. How would that work?

Thanks a ton guys!
~Chad

Comment: Is your controller method decorated with [HttpPost] where its being submitted? Also I suggest you use javascript with the checkboxes for showing certain questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, using the Html helpers like CheckBoxFor inside for loops caused problems for me because I didn't have control over the ids of the input tags that were generated. Check the final markup that is rendered and see what the ids of the  controls it is making are. Writing out the html for the  controls isn't really that much longer then calling the helper method anyway.

Comment: Thanks @innerexception you're right. Now just one more question how would an example html tag look for that example?